# Notepad++ displays code point values instead of characters in html files converted from docs

Tags: html, utf-8, ms-word, notepad++, codepoint

I have two words documents, which I converted to HTML by using Word conversion (Save as html page). The content in is Hebrew and English in both documents.
Afterwards I opened both documents with Notepad++:

- In the first document everything was displayed well and I could see hebrew characters.
- In the second document, I didn't see a single hebrew character, but code points values. For example, here is a piece of content from the html page (just without the " marks):

  "&#1502";"&#1508";"&#1512";"&#1511";
    "&#1508";"&#1506";"&#1497";"&#1500";

I used of course the same Word and Notepad++ applications, on the same machine, etc. If anyone has an idea about a possible cause to this phenomena, or/and how to overcome it (I want to see the Hebrew characters and not their code points), I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance!